# Google Tag Manager Analytics Option Not working properly

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a site **https://sample.com/** and have implemented Google Analytics option using Google Tag Manager last year and it was working perfectly in the site. But for the last 2-3 months we are not receiving any analytics data and the no of visit count shows '0' every time.

I am using a VueJS application and I have added the script in index.html.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

Any thoughts on if the website has a problem or a reason why I'm not getting analytics?

Comment: This may help - https://webdeasy.de/en/vue-analytics-en/. If not can you show the file in which you have added the script ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Vue plugin for Google Analytics? https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics

You can find find here information about how to install it: https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics/blob/master/docs/installation.md